# Redirect syntax issue in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to redirect a php page. the following is my php script :

```
    $url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header("Location: $url/suppliers");
```

But the php page throws error saying invalid redirect error. i am not understanding what the problem is. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try like this:

```
header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/suppliers");
exit();
```

Comment: @Sanju welcome but I got one negative vote on my anwer. its okay.

Comment: sorry for that. But its not me. :)